# Error after Running .Exe (but no error from Debugger)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code which basically takes QCs from a BaseFolder and Deploys the Patches.

The problem is:

When I run the code using "Debug" or "Release" mode from VS 2010, it works fine and gives the result.
But when I run the .exe directly from \bin\release\ or \bin\debug\ folder, it gives me connectivity errors and the application stops.

On research I have found that, if I build my .exe after commenting out the following 2 "retval" statements and hardcoding to 1, then the exe works fine:

```
//retVal = Olf.NetToolkit.Util.ScriptImport(avsFilename.ToString(), avsFormatedName.ToString(), (int)fileType);
```

retval = 1;

```
//retVal = olfTKAttach.Attach();
```

retval = 1;

Do let me know if there are any pointers to solve the problem?
    (( Recap In brief: Code and UI working perfectly from Debugger, but not when I run the exe. :(  ))

Comment: What does ScriptImport method do? Is the filename/path correct?

Comment: It imports the scripts from the basefolder location. The folder path is correct, as I can run it easily from the debugger. But not directly from the exe.

Comment: Is there a config file in your app used by these calls?  If so is it getting properly copied to the bin folder?

Comment: Checked, Tony; it gets copied properly.